# Windows 8 app: Best way to build this fency different sized layouts?

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I had a look at the windows 8 app development resources and there are always this fency layouts with different templated items (see below) but I could not find a sample how this should be done.

[image: image with sample for the requested layout]

Does anyone have a sample or even know how to do it?

**update**

Maybe the question is a little bit to unclear.
I want to know how the designs you can see in all the Windows 8 demo apps and in the image above are done. For example often there are different headlines (friends, restaurants, wishlist,...) with lists below. This lists contain sometimes images that are, lets say 10x10, and others are 20x10 (see 3 col in the image). Is there a build in and easy way to achieve this or do they just stack lists and templates (using stackpanels and such things) somehow?

Comment: Thats what I had trouble with as well, when I started with windows phone development back then. There are hardly any resources or guidance about the design regarding layouting, how much the spacing should be etc... I basically just started the emulator and made screenshots of apps of the OS to find those things out.

Comment: I guess thats the same now with Windows 8 metro apps. I would recommend looking at existing apps and how they do it. This is really important to create a consistent look and feel. I wonder why there are not more people asking for this.

Comment: If you are looking for such things maybe have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872191 (where the img is from). What I want to know is the best way to create such UIs they are showing at the developer resources all the time. Means which controls can be used and so on...

Comment: Oh great, have to bookmark that site. Now I suddenly feel like creating a Win8 app myself :)

Comment: What do you mean with "which controls can be used"? The standard controls you have given in expression blend should do it, dont they? Listviews, grids, stackpanels, etc...

Comment: As i know from WP7 development there is for example a ListBox, which has a DataTemplate (containing other controls) and so all bound items are displayed. But i dont know how i can create a ListView, GridView or what ever they are using to achieve such a layout.

Comment: Sorry, I dont have the Windows 8 developer tools installed, so I cannot verify it, but I guess it is like with WP7: just open the project in expression blend and to the right in the toolbar you have a button 'objects' that opens a dialog with all controls like listviews etc... also, grid, canvas and stackpanel even have an own button in the toolbar.

Comment: I will play a little bit with it... maybe there is someone who can give me an advice if what will come is good practice or just a fail =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found something in the documentation of the developmentcenter:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465351

There is a control called "VariableSizedWrapGrid" which handle this layouts!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid